# States changing over time, list all objects that had state x = y between time A and time B

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I'm building a database to store states of objects. That states e.g. color changes over time.

I want to query all objects that had a specific state within a given time, e.g. all that had the color green at least once between 1pm and 2pm at a given day.

My Idea was a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE states (
  type text,
  value text,
  name text,
  timestamp timeuuid,
  primary key ((type, value), timestamp, name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

Given some testdata:

```
// A, becomes green, turns red and back to green
insert into states(type, value, name, timestamp) values ('color', 'red', 'A',  minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T12:00:00+0000'));
insert into states(type, value, name, timestamp) values ('color', 'green', 'A',  minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T13:35:00+0000'));
insert into states(type, value, name, timestamp) values ('color', 'red', 'A',  minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T13:42:00+0000'));
insert into states(type, value, name, timestamp) values ('color', 'green', 'A',  minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T13:45:00+0000'));


// B stays red
insert into states(type, value, name, timestamp) values ('color', 'red', 'B',  minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T01:00:00+0000'));


// C stays green
insert into states(type, value, name, timestamp) values ('color', 'green', 'C',  minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T11:27:00+0000'));

// D becomes red
insert into states(type, value, name, timestamp) values ('color', 'green', 'D',  minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T13:00:00+0000'));
insert into states(type, value, name, timestamp) values ('color', 'red', 'D',  minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T13:27:00+0000'));

 type  | value | system.dateof(timestamp) | name
-------+-------+--------------------------+------
 color | green | 2016-07-07 13:45:00+0000 |    A
 color | green | 2016-07-07 13:35:00+0000 |    A
 color | green | 2016-07-07 13:00:00+0000 |    D
 color | green | 2016-07-07 11:27:00+0000 |    C
 color |   red | 2016-07-07 13:42:00+0000 |    A
 color |   red | 2016-07-07 13:27:00+0000 |    D
 color |   red | 2016-07-07 12:00:00+0000 |    A
 color |   red | 2016-07-07 01:00:00+0000 |    B
```

What I would like to get is A,C,D and not B since it was not green within the timerange.

And a simple between query:

`select name from states where type = 'color' and value = 'green' and timestamp >= minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T13:00:00+0000') and timestamp < minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T14:00:00+0000');`

I get `A,A,D` as a result. I cannot use distinct here, because `"SELECT DISTINCT queries must only request partition key columns and/or static columns (not name)"` but I could live with duplicates because they are easy to handle on the application side.

The main problem with this query is that it cannot detect C, since the color was already green before the timerange and did not change within.

**Update**

I can modify the database howsoever I want, but `I cannot specify when the connected devices send updates. They just send data as their state changes and the middleware has to be stateless` The timerange is user defined at query time and I cannot (and don't want to) set it to fixed ranges.

**Is there a well known pattern for that?**

Comment: Sorry but: i don't understand your problem. Your selected timerange is between 1pm and 2pm. C isn't in this timerange.

Comment: @PhilippBlum C got green at 2016-07-07T11:27:00+0000 and kept its state. It wasn't changed to another color so it was still green between 1pm and 2pm.

Comment: one thing you could do is modifiy your data every timerange you want to query. another possible thing is to store a state of all your object everytime you will query them. Could you give more information about your database?

Comment: This is essentially querying whether a time range in the database overlaps with a specified time range. You could modify the database to store the end of the time range (right now you're only storing the start), and if the state has no end, leave it as infinite. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178825/cassandra-overlapping-data-ranges) for methods to query overlapping time ranges.

Comment: @spiffman that could work but I would need to read the current state, then write the end-value to it and append the new state. Read before write is an antipattern and I think this could leed to wrong data when state changes occur fast enough.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is possible to achieve what you want using User Defined Function And User Defined Aggregates which accepts literal values (this is being done by JIRA [CASSANDRA-10783](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10783)). Let me explain how it could be implemented:

1. Create an accumulatorFunction called `is_in_interval()` (see below for code example)
2. Create an aggregate `matching_objects_in_interval()` (see below for code example)
3. Use this aggregate in your query

Implementation example (does not compile without patch from [CASSANDRA-10783](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10783))

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_in_interval(state set<text>, name text, timestamp timeuuid, 
min_date timeuuid, max_date timeuuid)
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS set<text>
LANGUAGE java
AS $$
    // The object has it timestamp inside the provided date range
    if(timestamp.compareTo(min_date) >= 0 &&
       timestamp.compareTo(max_date) <= 0) {
       // We don't care adding multiple time because Set eliminates duplicates anyway 
       state.add(name);
    }
    return state;
$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE IF NOT EXISTS matching_objects_in_interval(text, timeuuid, timeuuid, timeuuid)
SFUNC is_in_interval
STYPE set<text>
// {} is the Cassandra LITERAL SYNTAX for empty set
INITCOND {};
```

Usage:

```
SELECT matching_objects_in_interval(name, timestamp, minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T13:00:00+0000'), minTimeuuid('2016-07-07T14:00:00+0000'))
FROM states 
WHERE type = 'color' 
AND value = 'green';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hope I can test it soon. Can you explain how a value would be matched, there the state were set to green `before the min_date` and keept its state throughout the selected timerange? This would be `C` in the example.

Comment: In your case you should probably update the function and aggregate to track state changes for each **name**. For example instead of having state = list<text> it would be state = map<text, timeuuid> with timeuuid = the **last** time the state has changed for a given name