# Cassandra - do group by and join in the right way

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I know - Cassandra does not supports `group by`. But how to achieve similar result on a big collection of data.
Let's say I have table with 1 mln rows of `clicks`, 1 mln with `shares` and table `user_profile`. `clicks` and `shares` store one operation per row with `created_at` column. On a dashboard I would like to show results grouped by day, for example:

```
2016-06-01 - 2016-07-01

+-------------+--------+------+
|user_profile |  like  |share |
+-------------+--------+------+
| John        | 34     | 12   |
| Adam        | 12     | 4    |
| Bruce       | 4      | 2    |
+-------------+--------+------+
```

The question is, how can I do this in the right way:

1. Create table user_likes_shares with `counter` by date
2. Create UDF to `group by` each column and join them in the code by merging arrays by key
3. Select data from 3 tables group and join them in the code by merging arrays by key
4. Another option

If you use code to join the results, do you use Apache Spark SQL, Is the Spark the right way in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra group by and filter results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683872/cassandra-group-by-and-filter-results)

Comment: Could you provide the schemas for the tables? Also what are your grouping by? (I am guessing it's by a URL?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your dashboard page will show all historical results, grouped by day:

**1. 'Group by' in a table:** The denormalised approach is the accepted way of doing things in Cassandra as [writes and disk space are cheap](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling). If you can structure your data model (and application writes) to support this, then this is the best approach.

**2. 'Group by' in a UDA:** In this [blog post](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1876), the author notes that all rows are pulled back to the coordinator, reconciled and aggregated there (for CL>1). So even if your `clicks` and `shares` tables are partitioned by date, Cassandra will still have to pull all rows for that date back to the coordinator, store them in the JVM heap and then process them. So this approach has reduced scalability.

**3. Merging in code:** This will be a much slower approach as you will have to transfer a lot more data from the coordinator to your application server.

**4. Spark:** This is a good approach if you have to make ad-hoc queries (e.g. analyzing data, rather than populating a web page) and can be simplified by running your Spark jobs through a notebook application (a.g. [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/)). However, in your use case, you have the complexity of having to wait for that job to finish, write the output somewhere and then display it on a web page.

Comment: can you share how to do in spark? using normal groupBy method or sql with DataFrame?

Comment: As per the [Spark-Cassandra driver documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#grouping-rows-by-partition-key), _spanBy_/_spanByKey_ should be preferred over _groupBy_ to reduce shuffling. With regard to using SparkSQL, I don't know if the "GROUP BY" statement would be translated into _spanBy_.